# How can I reuse the socket.io emit function? Trying to attach the socket emit function to the SwiftUI button (action)?

Tags: swiftui, socket.io, init

I am new to SwitftUI and Xcode.
I am trying to re-use the send/emit function  which is in the class -> init() section.
However, when I try to call the function into the button (action), the Xcode will say 'cannot find scope'. I realised the problem is cause my function is inside the 'init()'. However, I tried and failed to bring out the lines code out of the 'init()'.

The line of code right below 'init()', 'let socket = manager.defaultSocket' cant be pull out from the init(). And when I pull out the paragraph of code to the class section, I get errors like 'socket' or no such work as 'emit'.
I been stuck at this problem for many days.

I have tried to group the emit code into a func to put it on a button func but Xcode do not recognise it, this is my sendmsg func, I will have alot of compiling errors if i bring this func out of the 'init()'

```
func sendMsg(){
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect){ (data, ack) in
        print("Connected")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","Hi server111")
            socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","testing")
            sleep(UInt32(0.3))
    }}
```

[This is the error I got when I put it into the button action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNUT9.png)

Below is my full and working code but not completed. My code is able to connect, receive msg but only able to send msg once when it is connected. I am trying to send continuously msg to node js from my SwiftUI Button.

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO
import zlib


final class Service: ObservableObject {

    @Published var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"ws://localhost:4044")!, config:[.log(true), .compress])
    @Published var messages = [String]()
    
   func sendMsgFunc(){
   }

    
    init(){
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket

        _sendMsg()
        func _sendMsg(){
            socket.on(clientEvent: .connect){ (data, ack) in 
                print("Connected")
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","Hi server111") 
                    socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","testing") 
                    sleep(UInt32(0.3))
            }}}
        
        socket.on("iOS Client Port"){ [weak self] (data, ack) in //receive
            if let data = data[0] as? [String: String],
               let rawMessage = data["msg"] {  
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self?.messages.append(rawMessage)
                    print(rawMessage)
                    socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","msg received")
                    sleep(UInt32(0.3))
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        socket.connect()
        
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var service = Service()
    @State var test: String = ""
    @State var textFieldText: String = ""
    @State var dataArray: [String] = []

    var body: some View { 
        
        VStack{
            Text("Received messages")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            Button("Click", action: service.sendMsgFunc)
            Button("Connect .2"){
                print("hello .2")
            }

            ForEach(service.messages, id: \.self) { msg in
                Text(msg).padding() // Receive from Js
            }
            
        }

    }
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
}


----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let socket = ...` can be repeated wherever you need it. So, if you need it in `init`, you can include it there. If you need it in `sendMsg()`, you can include it there as well.

Because you have some mismatched braces in your code, it's a *little* challenging to tell exactly where you want everything to happen, but this seems like it would fit your needs:

```
final class Service: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"ws://localhost:4044")!, config:[.log(true), .compress])
    @Published var messages = [String]()
    
    init(){
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        sendMsg()
        socket.connect()
    }
    
    func sendMsg(){
        let socket = manager.defaultSocket
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect){ (data, ack) in
            print("Connected")
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","Hi server111")
                socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","testing")
                sleep(UInt32(0.3))
            }}
        
        socket.on("iOS Client Port"){ [weak self] (data, ack) in //receive
            if let data = data[0] as? [String: String],
               let rawMessage = data["msg"] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self?.messages.append(rawMessage)
                    print(rawMessage)
                    socket.emit("NodeJS Server Port","msg received")
                    sleep(UInt32(0.3))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, this is what I needed! Thank you so much for your time!